# Table 'DBNAME.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a SpringBoot 2.0.1.RELEASE application using spring data / jpa

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But when I do an update in the  Amazon Aurora DB, I got this error:

> 2018-04-13 09:20  [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR o.h.id.enhanced.TableStructure.execute(148) - could not read a hi value
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'elbar.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

I have this in the entity I want to save

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
```

I would like to avoid also any drawback in the DB to fetch the ID .

Answer (score 220, accepted):

With the generation  `GenerationType.AUTO` hibernate will look for the default `hibernate_sequence` table , so change generation to  `IDENTITY`  as below :

```
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;
```

Comment: https://vladmihalcea.com/why-should-not-use-the-auto-jpa-generationtype-with-mysql-and-hibernate/ clearly explains what changed between Hibernate 3 and 5 major versions on handling on GenerationType.AUTO

Answer (score 27):

Add the following config in your application.yml:

`spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      use-new-id-generator-mappings: false`

Or this if you use application.properties

`spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings= false`

Answer (score 14):

If you are using Hibernate version prior to Hibernate5 `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` works like a charm. But post Hibernate5 the following fix is necessary.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO,generator="native")
@GenericGenerator(name = "native",strategy = "native")
private Long id;
```

**DDL**

```
`id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

**REASON**

Excerpt from [hibernate-issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11014)

> Currently, if the hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings is set to false,
>   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) is mapped to native. 
>   If this property is true (which is the defult value in 5.x), the
>   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) is always mapped to
>   SequenceStyleGenerator.
>
> For this reason, on any database that does not support sequences
>   natively (e.g. MySQL) we are going to use the TABLE generator instead
>   of IDENTITY.
>
> However, TABLE generator, although more portable, uses a separate
>   transaction every time a value is being fetched from the database. In
>   fact, even if the IDENTITY disables JDBC batch updates and the TABLE
>   generator uses the pooled optimizer, the IDENTITY still scales better.

Answer (score 9):

Just in case you migrate from a previous boot version:

setting the following in your `application.yml` will prevent hibernate from looking for `hibernate_sequence` entries.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings
```

That was the default in Boot 1.x

Answer (score 6):

> **Warning** : This will truncate the data in all tables specified as entities in your application

## JPA and Auto-DDL

When I run into mapping mismatches between a table schema and a java entity I like to do the following.

1. Drop the schema
2. Add the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` property to **application.properties**
3. Restart your application

This will now recreate the schema based on your entity.   You can then compare the created table against your old schema to see the difference, if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can just create the table:

```
create table hibernate_sequence(
    next_val INTEGER NOT null
);
```

Answer (score 2):

just add this code to your application.properties file

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when I used the following dialect setting:

```
# Hibernate SQL dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

I am using MySQL version 8.0.27, aftter I updated the above setting to:

```
# Hibernate SQL dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

Then it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` in the propoerties file solved the issue

Comment: Very Bad Solution. As `create-drop` and `create` both will destroy all your previous data

Answer (score 0):

Since I had Server version: 8.0.29 MySQL Community Server - GPL (which you can check from many places, I found from MySQL Command Line client)

In hibernate configuration file
earlier I was trying with:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
```

Replacing it with following:

```
<property name="spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>
```

It worked absolutely fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.Auto) 
 private Long id;
```

change `GenerationType.Auto` to `GenerationType.IDENTITY`

Answer (score 0):

**Just add the following config in your application.properties**

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Answer (score 0):

i am using struts, and migrating from hibernate 3 to 5. I updated the property in my persistence.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false" />
```