# GenerationType.IDENTITY not generated in SpringBoot 2.1.5.RELEASE & MySQL 8.0.15

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, junit, spring-data-jpa

I have a basic SpringBoot 2.1.5.RELEASE app. Using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

I have this domain class:

```
     @Entity
        @Table(name="t_purchase")
        @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
        public class Purchase implements Serializable {

            public Purchase() {
            }

            public Purchase(Shop shop) {
                super();
                this.shop = shop;
            }

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            @JsonProperty("id")
            private Long id;    

@JsonProperty("txHash")
    private String txHash;

            @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
            @JoinColumn(name = “shop_id")
            @JsonIgnore
            Shop shop;


    @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            Purchase purchase = (Purchase) o;

            if (getTxHash()==null && purchase.getTxHash()==null) {
                 return id == purchase.id;
            } else {
                return Objects.equals(getTxHash(), purchase.getTxHash());
            }
        }



        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int result = (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
            result = 31 * result + Objects.hash(getTxHash());
            return result;
        }

        …
        }
```

then I created this Junit method:

```
   @Test
    public void testFindByShopIdWithPurchases () {

        Shop shop = new Shop ("Shop_NAME");

        shopService.save(shop);

        Purchase purchase1 = new Purchase(shop);
        Purchase purchase2 = new Purchase(shop);

        shop.getPurchases().add(purchase1);
        shop.getPurchases().add(purchase2);

        shopService.save(shop);

        assertNotEquals (purchase1, purchase2);


    }
```

But I have an AssertionError, because it seems that for both objects id is 0:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Values should be different. Actual: Purchase [id=0, txHash=null, shop=957]
```

Here the Shop:

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = “t_shop")
    public class Shop implements Serializable {


        public Shop(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @JsonProperty("id")
        private Long id;

        @JsonProperty("name")
        private String name;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = “shop", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JsonIgnore
        private Set<Purchase> purchases = new HashSet<Purchase>();

            …
    }
```

Comment: Is your test annotated with `@Transactional`? If not, could you try to add that?

Comment: Indeed, it is :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @JsonProperty("id")
        private Long id;
```

As you are using GenerationType **IDENTITY**, it means you are responsible for generating ID instead if hibernate.

If you want application will auto manage the id generation then use GenerationType **Auto**
so update your GenerationType in **Purchase** as well as in **Shop** entity

```
 @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @JsonProperty("id")
        private Long id;
```

...........................................................................

If you will still get error after above changes:

```
 java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'shops_db.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist
```

By default, Hibernate generates key from hibernate_sequence table, we can disable it by setting this hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings to false.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false
```

set this property in your application.properties

Answer (score 0):

Changing the type to AUTO solved the problem for me

Comment: I got this error when changing to AUTO: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'shops_db.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist

Comment: Please share the  hibernate.ddl-auto settings for your application

Answer (score 0):

try changing the property mentioned below
  **spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false**  
as new spring boot version 2.XX has changed this property to
  **spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=true**  
use below link for detailed understanding
[Table 'DBNAME.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49813666/table-dbname-hibernate-sequence-doesnt-exist/49813851)

Answer (score 0):

From Spring 2.X.X RELEASE, `spring-data-jpa` module using Hibernate5 version. If you explore the `org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:2.1.5.RELEASE` pom.xml file you find out the version of hibernate dependency as

```
<hibernate>5.2.17.Final</hibernate>
```

The Hibernate version prior to Hibernate5 `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` works like a charm. But post Hibernate5 the following  [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49813666/table-dbname-hibernate-sequence-doesnt-exist/58749481#58749481) is necessary.

Duplicating my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49813666/table-dbname-hibernate-sequence-doesnt-exist/58749481#58749481) here for posterity.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO,generator="native")
@GenericGenerator(name = "native",strategy = "native")
private Long id;
```

**DDL**

```
`id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

**REASON**

Excerpt from [hibernate-issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11014)

> Currently, if the hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings is set to false,
>   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) is mapped to native. 
>   If this property is true (which is the defult value in 5.x), the
>   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) is always mapped to
>   SequenceStyleGenerator.
>
> For this reason, on any database that does not support sequences
>   natively (e.g. MySQL) we are going to use the TABLE generator instead
>   of IDENTITY.
>
> However, TABLE generator, although more portable, uses a separate
>   transaction every time a value is being fetched from the database. In
>   fact, even if the IDENTITY disables JDBC batch updates and the TABLE
>   generator uses the pooled optimizer, the IDENTITY still scales better.