# JpaSystemException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I've been trying to create a new Student field that could be added into my MySQL database.

I'm using Spring Boot, MySQL Workbench and from my understanding everything is just as it should be - yet - it's still not working correctly.

This is how my Student class look like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "studenttab")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "sname")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "scourse")
    private String course;
    @Column(name = "sfee")
    private Double fee;
```

And this is how my test method looks like:

```
 @Test
    void testCreateStudent() {
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setName("Łukasz");
        student.setCourse("WoW-Best-Gold-Guide");
        student.setFee(100.00);
        studentRepository.save(student);
    }
```

StudentRepository is just extending a CrudRepository.

It seems like Hibernate is not able to create Ids automatically, which should be done by @GeneratedValue annotation.
Not sure what's wrong and what I can do to repair it.

¯_( ツ )_/¯

Comment: How is it "not working correctly" ? Do you have any errors or stack traces ?

Comment: Yea, exactly the same as the topic title

Answer (score 0):

You have choosen `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` - which means that you leave id-generation to database identity column (i.e. auto-incremented column in the database).
So you can:

1. Update database: make `id` field in the `studenttab` table auto-incremented on database level.
2. **Or** update Hibernate id-generation strategy to `AUTO` or remove it at all which is the same (as AUTO is the default strategy). In that case Hibernate will create id's on its own based on the id java-type.

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;

Note: since Hibernate 5.x in AUTO-mode, by default, uses db-sequences to generate the new ids, the 2nd approach will work only in the databases which support sequences.

If DB does not support sequences, Hibernate will use `Table-generator` for id-generation. So it will look for `hibernate_sequence` table, which you should either create by yourself or Hibernate can create it for you, if you set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` property to `update` or `create`.

If you are using Hibernate earlier than 5.x, or using 5.x and `spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings= false`, it will use again IDENTITY by default and you will see the same error.

For more details read here (all answers, not the accepted one): [Table 'DBNAME.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49813666/table-dbname-hibernate-sequence-doesnt-exist)

Comment: I did try changing GeneratioType to AUTO, didn't help, same error

Comment: @Vinci, so you need to try the 1st approach. Hibernate uses sequences for id-generation and MySQL does not support them. There are workarounds for that (using additional tables as a sequence), so the easiest way is to make id column auto-incremented.

Comment: Please, see the updated answer