# Liquibase hibernate sequence tabel dosen't exist

Tags: liquibase-hibernate

Table 'liquibase_db.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist.So I am getting this type of error while I post data from the postman. I tried to solve that problem I tried to add hibernate sequence It's not working.

Answer (score 0):

With the generation `GenerationType.AUTO` hibernate will look for the default `hibernate_sequence` table , so change generation to `IDENTITY` as below :

```
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;
```

Reference:

- 200+ accepted as answer to: [Table 'DBNAME.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49813666/table-dbname-hibernate-sequence-doesnt-exist)